# NPM error on any command

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

I downloaded the latest version of Node.js (0.8.8) and it works all fine and dandy, but the NPM that is packaged with the Node.js installation is now failing. It worked when I had an outdated version of Node.js (0.5.x) and I could type commands like

```
npm --version
```

and It would return the current version of NPM. However when I do any command (even the one above) I receieve this error

```
$ npm -v

/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/config-defs.js:5
  , stdio = process.binding("stdio")
                ^
Error: No such module
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/config-defs.js:5:21)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/ini.js:43:18)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
```

I am using NPM version 1.1.59

**Note:** I have tried updating NPM with

```
$ curl -L curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to [Sean's comment on an answer at his own post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199083/863186), I got it. After I removed the npm module from

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/
```

and the binary from

```
/usr/bin/
```

It's all now working.

I think after installing the latest Node.js it might have conflicted, because both paths were global. Hope this helps anyone in the future :-)

Comment: works for me too, I think the problem comes from when you installed an old package not from the main node distro site and then try to install an authentic one ontop.